# How to get current Workflow XML for active Instance by the Rest API

Tags: bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io, camunda-modeler

In my AngularApp i will show the User the current Workflow, by using the REST API.
No Problem so far, usnig:

> GET /process-definition/{id}/xml

and the

> bpmn.io Viewer.

But it's possible to highlight the current Task or get the special Instance of the Workflow, with highlight the current Task?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Get actual the task

The call `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task/?processInstanceId=<processInstanceId>` return a [json with the taskDefinitionKey](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/get-query/#result).

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/get-query/

## 2. Style the task

You can add a style class and so highlight a task.

```
viewer.importXML(diagramXML, function() {
    var canvas = viewer.get('canvas');
    canvas.addMarker('<<TaskId>>', 'highlight');
});
```

CSS for the color:

```
.highlight:not(.djs-connection) .djs-visual > :nth-child(1) {
    fill: green !important; /* color elements as green */
}
```

The example is from https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/colors#adding-colors

Comment: I think its the "taskDefinitionKey" not the "TaskId" right?

Comment: up vote
-1
down vote
accept
Thanks a lot for the support, my CSS doesn't work properly yet. The task will be highlighted, but unfortunately it is not colored.

<g class="djs-element djs-shape highlight" data-element-id="Task_1x7c62x">

Maybe you can help me again.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping me out. To make it work as you described, you have to change the ViewEncapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None in the Angular.ts file.